# manipulating external images in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

If i import an external image in as3, is it possible to manipulate it? I would like to have the corners curled a bit like its a piece of paper, would this be possible in code? I thought you could transform images etc but have no idea where to begin.

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't. The papervision library manipulates images in all different ways. I don't see you couldn't either.

Comment: Start with the BitmapData class and its methods, move to filters and see what you can do with Convolution/Displacement/etc. for example, then if that will not what you want, start playing with PixelBender. As on as you have a cross domain xml which grants you access to the pixels of the image you're loading externally, you're free to modify those as much as you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the basic manipulations described by @jhocking you can use PixelBender to create more complex effects like the page curl you would like.

PixelBender is not ActionScript; it's actually an entirely different language and may be pretty hard to grasp at first. There are two steps in creating a PixelBender shader for use in ActionScript:

1. you create a PixelBender kernel and compile it. This kernel will read every pixel of your image, transform it as desired and then return those transformed pixels.
2. you create a ShaderJob that uses this compiled kernel and assign it to the 'filters' property of whatever visual component you want to apply the effect to.

For more information, tutorials and video's go to devnet: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pixelbender.html

You can find an example of a page curl PixelBender shader here: http://superflashbros.net/2010/06/28/a-real-page-turner/

and here's the demo: http://superflashbros.net/curl/

Comment: I've been meaning to start playing with PixelBender so that looks like a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Some basic manipulations are possible, like tinting the image. You can't really do anything intricate like curling the corners in ActionScript however.

Depending on your exact use case there are a variety of ways of faking that effect, such as pasting images of curled paper over your external image.