# Flash Flip Page curl effect in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, curl, flip

I am working on a project which needs to develop a flip-page (curl) effect using flash like the below example: http://www.actionscript.org/showMovie.php?id=459

I found many example which all of those are using AS1.0/2.

As I want some program extension in AS 3.0 for my project, does anyone know any example, tutor or product on AS3 flash flip page effects?

Indeed, I have found a free-plugin called megazine3 (http://www.megazine3.de/home.html) to do that, but its source file is too complicated which I can't edit and add features on it, so may anyone know any other way to do that?

Comment: I have already answered this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364262/manipulating-external-images-in-actionscript-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an awesome open source Flex project by Ruben Swieringa: http://www.rubenswieringa.com/code/as3/flex/Book/

It has many features like transparent pages, hard covers, page tearing etc. It uses bitmap transformations to do the actual flipping.

It is based on some online tutorial which I can't find now, last time I checked it was like 2 or 3 years ago. It's is much simpler engine and uses masks instead of bitmaps for flipping. But this also allows you to embed interactive content (anchors, linking to other pages, audio/video, animations etc.). I don't host the code online but if you're interested maybe I can share it.

Comment: Link is broken; please fix. (I have [removed the broken link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179253/218334).)

Answer (score 0):

Why not to take basic page-flip AS2 engine and rewrite it to AS3 to meet your requirements? Page flip code (inside fla) found here  http://pageflip.hu/pageflip2/pageflip_v225_source.php is clear and well commented.