# how to flip a movieclip as if we are reading a printed book in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How can we flip some movie clips one by one as if you are reading a printed book?

I need to create a ebook in as3 where we are populating dynamic data.

Here, is a link which I got while searching, http://swf-flash.blogspot.in/2010/07/let-talk-about-how-to-create-pageflip.html#more But, its using a static movieclip, whereas i need a movieclip with dynamic content.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's quite a lot of page flip solutions out there. I don't think dynamic content should make much difference. See a list here http://flashspeaksactionscript.com/flip-a-page-with-these-flash-page-flippers/

Comment: Thanks for the help.. But I just want the as3 code to flip a number of movieclips as if we are turning the pages of a book. Is there any free help on how to do that?

Comment: have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463143/flash-flip-page-curl-effect-in-as3 .. It has a link to a PageFlip.as class u in the first package here: http://www.rubenswieringa.com/code/as3/flex/Book/source/index.html

Answer (score -2):

you can learn more from this site http://www.flashandmath.com/flashcs4/flip/index.html

good luck

Comment: thanks for the reply.. The link you provided is good but its just flipping the movieclip but i want to flip the movieclip as if we are turning a book page. How to do that?